# jQuery selector, contains to equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the folowing selector

```
    var likeComperssionOption = $('select[id*=ComparisionType]').eq(0)
                                            .find("option:contains('LIKE')");
```

this checks for an option which **contains** the word 'like' right?

How do i find an option which is **exactly** with the word 'like'?

Somthing like this:

```
     var likeComperssionOption = $('select[id*=ComparisionType]').eq(0)
                                            .find("option:equals('LIKE')");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just select all the options from the `select` and filter them by `text()` value:

```
var likeComperssionOption = $('select[id*=ComparisionType]:first option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == "LIKE" });
```

Comment: It didn't work.
The "like" is in the text.When i use the alert to show the value of 
alert(likeComperssionOption.val()); I get undefined.
But when i used the "conatins" (as in the question) The same alert displays "3"

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had " Like " with spaces that's why It didn't work for me. Is there a trim function?

Comment: Fixed. 
 return jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == 'LIKE';

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select based on the `value` attribute of the options, you need to use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select elements with a specific value for their `value` attribute:

```
var likeComperssionOption = $('select[id*=ComparisionType]').eq(0)
                           .find("option[value='LIKE']")
```

Otherwise, to select based on the display text of the options, use:

```
var likeComperssionOption = $('select[id*=ComparisionType]').eq(0)
                           .find("option").filter(function() {
                               return $(this).text() == 'LIKE';
                           });
```

**Update:** You might be having some problems with your initial selector, it looks very strange. You should probably change

```
$('select[id*=ComparisionType]').eq(0)
```

to something simple like

```
$('#ComparisionType')
```

The concept of this answer works fine, you can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/MsTsb/).

Comment: i can have value="1" and text="LIKE": `<option value="1">LIKE</option>`

Comment: It didn't work.
The "like" is in the text.When i use the alert to show the value of 
alert(likeComperssionOption.val()); I get undefined.
But when i used the "conatins" (as in the question) The same alert displays "3"

Comment: @Aharon: It works for me. See my update and check out the link.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I had " Like " with spaces that's why It didn't work for me. Is there a trim function?

Comment: Fixed. 
 return jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == 'LIKE';