# :eq for text similar to :contains in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a selector that matches an exact text match? For example if I have a `<select>` with Matt Black and Black, and I try to do `'#field option:contains("Black")'` I'll get Matt Black although I want to select Black.

:eq looks for Index *n* - is there a better way to select an `<option>` node based on it's textual content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery selector, contains to equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344220/jquery-selector-contains-to-equals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('someElement').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Some text';
});
```