# jQuery error when extending object prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I extend the `Object` prototype and try to use some functions of jQuery 2.0.3 I get errors...

[For example <sup>jsFiddle</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/436Zq/)

```
Object.prototype.GetHashCode = function() { return 1; };
$(document).on("click", "div", function() { });
```

If I do this and then click any div I get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { return 1; } has no method 'exec'
```

Why does it happen? Is there a workaround or a way to fix this bug in jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296340/how-to-define-method-in-javascript-on-array-prototype-and-object-prototype-so-th)

Comment: @Chandu: OK, it doesn't exactly answer the question. *Why does this happen?* - because you're destroying all `for in` property enumerations with extending the `Object.prototype`. It is not a bug in jQuery. *Is there a workaround?* - see the linked duplicate

Comment: Seems like a jquery bug...by the way this works fine `$('div').click(function() { console.log('div clicked'); });`

Comment: @NaveenBhat: No, it is not a jQuery bug. It is just that a `for in` loop is used in the code when a delegated event is triggered, but not for a directly attached handler.

Comment: You *really* shouldn't extend `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Stop saying I shouldn't use without a reasonable explanation why I shouldn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this JavaScript prototype function break jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941657/why-does-this-javascript-prototype-function-break-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this [report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14178) they say they don't want to fix that. So don't use Object.prototype when working with jquery.