# Including indexOf fix for Array.prototype causes Syntax error in jQuery 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to implement ECMA262-5 array method indexOf for browsers older than IE9. So far, I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and I have this code in my own jQuery plugin:

```
if($.support.opacity === false) {
    $.getScript(iptPluginUIFFront.location + 'js/ie8.js');
}
```

The ie8.js has the following code, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc).

```
'use strict';

// Add ECMA262-5 method binding if not supported natively
//
if (!('bind' in Function.prototype)) {
    Function.prototype.bind= function(owner) {
        var that= this;
        if (arguments.length<=1) {
            return function() {
                return that.apply(owner, arguments);
            };
        } else {
            var args= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return function() {
                return that.apply(owner, arguments.length===0? args : args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };
        }
    };
}

// Add ECMA262-5 string trim if not supported natively
//
if (!('trim' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.trim= function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    };
}

// Add ECMA262-5 Array methods if not supported natively
//
if (!('indexOf' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf= function(find, i /*opt*/) {
        if (i===undefined) i= 0;
        if (i<0) i+= this.length;
        if (i<0) i= 0;
        for (var n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                return i;
        return -1;
    };
}
if (!('lastIndexOf' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.lastIndexOf= function(find, i /*opt*/) {
        if (i===undefined) i= this.length-1;
        if (i<0) i+= this.length;
        if (i>this.length-1) i= this.length-1;
        for (i++; i-->0;) /* i++ because from-argument is sadly inclusive */
            if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                return i;
        return -1;
    };
}
if (!('forEach' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.forEach= function(action, that /*opt*/) {
        for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this)
                action.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    };
}
if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
        var other= new Array(this.length);
        for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this)
                other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
        return other;
    };
}
if (!('filter' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.filter= function(filter, that /*opt*/) {
        var other= [], v;
        for (var i=0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && filter.call(that, v= this[i], i, this))
                other.push(v);
        return other;
    };
}
if (!('every' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.every= function(tester, that /*opt*/) {
        for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && !tester.call(that, this[i], i, this))
                return false;
        return true;
    };
}
if (!('some' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.some= function(tester, that /*opt*/) {
        for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && tester.call(that, this[i], i, this))
                return true;
        return false;
    };
}
```

I am testing the IE8 behaviour in IE8 browser mode of IE10. It gives the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #function(find, i /*opt*/) {
        if (i===undefined) i= 0;
        if (i<0) i+= this.length;
        if (i<0) i= 0;
        for (var n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                return i;
        return -1;
    } 
jquery.js, line 4 character 15704
```

I guess this has something to do with jQuery itself, or is it just a bug in IE8 browser mode of IE10. Any help is really appreciated.

PS: I tried to do just the indexOf method instead of all the methods listed above. But that returned same error. Also, thinking that perhaps, jQuery 1.10.2 has it's own implementation of indexOf, I left the code off and tried to use indexOf on an array. But it failed in IE8 (just like it should).

Also please consider that using jQuery.inArray is not an option for me (unless of course I am forced to), as I am using position absolute validation engine which in turn uses indexOf in many cases.

**UPDATE**

As it seems, the error is basically coming from line 1850 of unminified jQuery version 1.10.2. It has the following code:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

Comment: IE8 document compatibility mode in IE10 is not the same as IE8.  That's a rendering mode, the javascript engine AFAIK is the same IE10 javascript engine.

Comment: i just tested indexOf() snippet under IE8 mode (IE10), cannot reproduce your issue. Any difference removing "use strict"; statement?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes I understand that. Perhaps that is causing the problem? But then again, under IE10, it works fine. (I will try force overriding the prototype).

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried that. But still it is throwing the error. Perhaps using jQuery 1.10.2 only will throw that error? I looked at the source code. It is basically WordPress' jQuery. So I couldn't get much info out of it as it is minified. I am going to replace with development version and update the question.

Comment: @SwashataGhosh ya sorry, i used 1.10.1, i'll test on 1.10.2

Comment: @A.Wolff I updated the question, please have a look. It seems the error is somewhere coming from jQuery. Also, I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I do have an embedded YouTube video and nivoSlider plugin.

Comment: i'd try to change `i===undefined` to `typeof i === "undefined"` even error seems to come from function(find, i /*opt*/). Anyway, you should try this shim instead: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js#L559

Comment: This is a known problem in jQuery, they don't check for `hasOwnProperty` on their for-in loops, and [won't change that](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14178). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724888/jquery-error-when-extending-object-prototype and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941657/why-does-this-javascript-prototype-function-break-jquery

Comment: A.Wolff Thanks for the tip

@bfavaretto Thanks for the answer. So, in theory, I can not implement the indexOf on Arrays? Or would a simple Array.indexOf = function() {} work?

Comment: I believe you can add indexOf using Object.defineProperty and making it not enumerable, [but that won't work in ie8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#ie8-specific)...

Comment: Thanks. I guess then I will just replace all indexOf in the jquery validation plugin with jQuery.inArray. Thanks again for all your explanations.