# Jquery hide span containing certain numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hide, html

I'm trying to perform a temporary quick hack on my website as I need to hide a few spans on a page and don't want to have to go through all the php to remove them permanently. So just want to hide them with jquery.

I want to use the `hide()` junction to hide spans containing any number from 1 to 9.

So on the page I have >>

```
 <span>good</span>
 <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
         <span>5</span>
             <span>ok</span>
```

etc... with the end one ending in `<span>bad</span>`

I have a list of about 30 of these, so want to do something like:

```
if span contains a number from 1-9, hide it.
```

I've used the `hide()` function before to hide things `onclick` etc, but I have no clue how to hide if the contents equals a number, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344220/jquery-selector-contains-to-equals/7344402#7344402 maybe this could help you somehow

Comment: can you provide a fiddle.that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ehmjm/

```
$("span").filter( function() {
    var num = Number($(this).text());
    return num >= 1 && num <= 9;
}).hide();
```

or by regex: http://jsfiddle.net/ehmjm/2/

```
$("span").filter( function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/^[1-9]$/);
}).hide();
```

Note: I'm assuming from your sample dom that you are looking to hide spans with just a number in it, if you are looking to hide stuff like "i have 5 dogs", you'll need to do something a bit different.

Comment: They are still there :( , its worth mentioning that the spans are created by jquery slider, this is an example <span class="ui-button-text">2</span>

Comment: I just need any with only numbers in them hiding :)

Comment: I don't see that they are still there, even with the example you just gave: http://jsfiddle.net/ehmjm/1/. If you are still seeing them, you'll want to make sure that your javascript is ran after the dom is built. Wrap the javascript in `$(document).ready(function() { [code here] });`

Comment: Got it !, I needed to wrap it in a document ready function :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').each(function(){
  if($(this).text().match(/^([1-9])$/))$(this).hide()
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/WnLUu/2/)

Comment: This will hide all numbers eg 52.

Comment: @vipulsharma sorry, my bad. I changed it now

Comment: For things like this it is generally better to use `filter` as you are wanting to apply the same change to everything that matches. With filter you can apply the change to all matches at once rather than each individually. Also, you are creating the same jquery object twice which also can have an affect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

ok I guess im late to the party. However this is my aproach:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bj26t/)

```
$('span').each(function(index, value) {
  if($(this).html() > 0 && $(this).html() < 10 )
  {
      $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is modifying each element individually and creating 3 (identical) jquery objects through each iteration in the process. These things are not good for performance. If you are going to be using the same jquery selector you can cache it like `$this = $(this)` and then use `$this` instead of creating a new jquery object for it.

Comment: Also, `1` would not pass your condition.